# Descriptions is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My code is

```
    var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        var weatherData = new Weather(cityName, data);
        weatherData.temperature = data.main.temp;
        updateWeather(weatherData);

    function Weather(cityName, data) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    data.weather[0].description = descriptions;
    this._temperature = '';
}

    function updateWeather(weatherData) {
    weatherCity.textContent = weatherData.cityName;
    weatherDescription.textContent = weatherData.descriptions;
    weatherTemperature.textContent = weatherData.temperature;

    loadingText.style.display = 'none';
    weather.style.display = 'block';
}
```

i get the error descriptions is not defined. works fine if i do this

```
var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        var weatherData = new Weather(cityName, data.weather[0].description);
        weatherData.temperature = data.main.temp;
        updateWeather(weatherData);

    function Weather(cityName, description) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    this.description = descriptions;
    this._temperature = '';
}

    function updateWeather(weatherData) {
    weatherCity.textContent = weatherData.cityName;
    weatherDescription.textContent = weatherData.descriptions;
    weatherTemperature.textContent = weatherData.temperature;

    loadingText.style.display = 'none';
    weather.style.display = 'block';
}
```

i have no clue what to do right now. am i not getting a value back? can someone fix it so i can understand. I'm new to this so this might be a stupid question. trying to do it the first way because i have more stuff i want to add like the weather pressure, wind speed, sunrise, etc.

Comment: I don't see any variable declared as `descriptions` in your code, so descriptions is not defined literally :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the below code block -

```
function Weather(cityName, description) {
this.cityName = cityName
this.description = descriptions;
this._temperature = '';
```

Please correct `this.description = descriptions` to `this.description = description`

Answer (score 0):

here

```
function Weather(cityName, description) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    this.description = descriptions;  // <--
    this._temperature = '';
}
```

you wrote `descriptions` instead of `description`